# no me guarda los datos ingresados del input en el floatval en php

Tags: php

En la cantidad lo cambie para q sea un input y cambiarle la cantidad pero no me lo guarda y no lo muestra en el floatval alguien que me ayude

```
<td><?php echo $lista->codigo;?></td>
<td><?php echo $lista->nombre;?></td>
<td>$<?php echo $lista->venta;?></td>
<td> <input type="number" value="<?php echo $lista->cantidad;?>" name="cantidad" id="cantidad<?php echo $lista->id;?>"></td>
<td>$<?php echo floatval($lista->cantidad * $lista->venta);?></td>
```

Comment: El código como texto y que muestre lo importante del problema, en tu caso donde y como estas guardando ese dato del input

Comment: solo tengo eso, creo que no lo estoy guardando me das algunas sugerencias para guardar ese dato

Comment: Hola @ackerman, En tu pregunta debes incluir un [ejemplo que sea mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) en texto. Nadie va a transcribir una imagen para verificar tu código, pero si se puede copiar y pegar para probarlo.

Comment: ´<td><?php echo $lista->codigo;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $lista->nombre;?></td>
                        <td>$<?php echo $lista->venta;?></td> 
      <td>
                        <input type="number" value="<?php echo $lista->cantidad;?>" name="cantidad" id="cantidad<?php echo $lista->id;?>">
      </td>  
      <td>$<?php echo floatval($lista->cantidad * $lista->venta);?></td> ´

Comment: Hola @ackerman, por favor, utiliza la opción [edit] y agrega toda información relevante en tu pregunta.

Comment: y como lo intentas guardar, y como lo intentas consultar... falta codigo para poder ayudarte...

Comment: edita la publicacion y agrega el codigo faltante tambien puedes actualizar y dar una mejor eplicacion...

Comment: antes de aplicar floatval, deberias saber que tipos de valores hay dentro. Si te das cuenta, estas haciendo la multiplicacion `dentro`del floatval. Si algun valor no es un float, la multiplicación no se hace correctamente, y luego aplicar el floatVal no te va a devolver nada. Lo suyo seria aplicar un floatval a cada uno de los operadores (algo como: `floatval($lista->cantidad) * floatval($lista->venta)`. aun asi, revisa e indicanos que te devuelve cada uno de los elementos.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos, ya lo termine